# Java/Kotlin UDP datagram

Tags: java, kotlin, udp, decode, datagram

I have a very basic question. Imagine one has a simple udp client, which is listening to incoming datagrams. Those datagrams are just byte[], but they may contain complex information, like Strings, ints and so on.

Is there any elegant way of decoding the datagram like using a struct defining the datagram content and a union in C, instead of working through the received byte[]  step by step with e.g. a ByteBuffer?

**EDIT 1**

Okay trying FlatBuffers now.
I can build a testproject to play around a little.
The first test I wanted to perform was to parse the simplest possible thing. Just one short (int16). I'm using this .fbs scheme

```
// Example IDL file for our monster's schema.

namespace UDPdatagram;


table DatContent {
    id:short;
}


root_type DatContent;
```

The minimal code I' trying to run is the following:

```
package controllingFXML

import UDPdatagram.DatContent
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

fun main() {
    // use a short (16 byte int, i.e. 2 byte)
    val byteArray           = ByteArray(2)
    // the test number
    val testShort: Short    = 67
    println("TEST SHORT: $testShort")

    // allocate a byte buffer and add the test short
    val buffer              = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteArray.size)
    buffer.position(0)
    buffer.putShort(testShort)

    // reset the position and verify its content
    buffer.position(0)
    val buffShort           = buffer.short
    println("BUFFER SHORT: $buffShort")

    // reset the position of the buffer again and try to use flatbuffers
    buffer.position(0)
    val content             =  DatContent.getRootAsDatContent(buffer)
    println("PARSED CONTENT: ${content.id()}")
}
```

Unfortunately I always get the following, when running the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:688)
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:392)
    at UDPdatagram.DatContent.getRootAsDatContent(DatContent.java:14)
    at UDPdatagram.DatContent.getRootAsDatContent(DatContent.java:13)
    at controllingFXML.AsdfKt.main(asdf.kt:25)
    at controllingFXML.AsdfKt.main(asdf.kt)
```

I'm totally lost. What am I missing here?

Comment: Either (i) `ByteBuffer` or (ii) `DataInputStream` wrapped around a `ByteArrayInputStream`, in both cases wrapped around the byte array. Or use `DatagramSocketChannel` directly with a `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: You are trying to fill data by yourself, but you should make it with FlatBuffers too. You should serialize data to FlatBuffers on one side and then deserialize from FlatBuffers it on the other side.

Comment: Why should I do that? If I get data over the network via a datagram it is simply a byte[], not necessarily having been constructed with flat buffers. I'm trying to "simulate" network data by constructing the ByteBuffer directly. It's just a test.

Comment: That is how flatbuffers work. You cannot just push short to buffer and parse it with flatbuffers, because flatbuffers uses it's own data storage format. You either should parse byte[] manually (with DataInputStream), or use FlatBuffers on both sides for data serialization to/from datagram.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. In that case flatbuffers is completely useless to me. I was just looking for a more concenient way of parsing byte[]. I get data over the network from sources not using flatbuffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either (i) ByteBuffer or (ii) DataInputStream wrapped around a ByteArrayInputStream, in both cases wrapped around the byte array. Or use DatagramSocketChannel directly with a ByteBuffer. – user207421

Answer (score 1):

There is no one to one solution in Java as in C.
More over it's not the best solution even in C as data interpretation depends on endiannes of the system.

But FlatBuffers library may be useful.

Comment: Okay I gave it a look, and it seems very nice!
However, the tutorial leaves me alone at some point.
What exactly should I do, after compiling the scheme? I don't get it, how to use the generated files.

Comment: To be more precise:
I copied the generated folder into my project. Unfortunately, when I build it, it states several errors, e.g. that it cannot find the symbol "BaseVector"

Comment: i have included com.google.flatbuffers flatbuffers-java version 1.11.1 in my pom.xml, so I don't get why there are these errors...

Comment: It simply does not find cetrain things from the package (like BaseVector), but finds other (like Table). It seems like the imported package from maven is missing some classes. How could that be?

Comment: Okay, now I've cloned the package and added it manually to my project. Now it builds. No idea why the maven import does not import everything.